# mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended

Tags: linux, centos

I am using CentOS 5.10 version with 64 bit, unfortunately when remove particular file under root directory the below error was strange :

```
**EXT3-fs warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended,rm: cannot remove `/var/lock/subsys/xinetd': Read-only file system**
```

it has changed to read-only file system, how to fix it ???

Comment: Run e2fsck on the file system, just as it recommends.

Answer (score 1):

If / is in read-only mode, first try remounting it with:

```
 mount -o remount,rw /
```

You'll still need to check the partition for errors. If you have physical access to server or a KVM
-boot it in single mode
-unmount all the partitions and run fsck

If you dont have a physical access, try

```
touch /forcefsck
```

This will force File System Check on the next reboot.